# How to update a table in SQL 2008 on daily/weekly basis

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have written a query to get some data from SOL 2008 standard edition and i want to insert the data into a table on daily/weekly basis.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a SQL Job to run daily or weekly as you desire. [MS SQL Server jobs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187910.aspx)